# react-chartjs-2 mixed type chart doesn't work with type in datasets

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
    labels: ['2021-10-29', '2021-10-30', '2021-10-31', '2021-11-01', '2021-11-02', '2021-11-03', '2021-11-04'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Coaching',
        data: [rand(), rand(), rand(), rand(), rand(), rand(), rand()],
        backgroundColor: `rgb(98.100.24)`,
      },
      {
        label: 'Away',
        data: [rand(), rand(), rand(), rand(), rand(), rand(), rand()],
        backgroundColor: `rgb(202,214,219)`,
      },
      {
        label: 'Total Call Count',
        data: [rand(), rand(), rand(), rand(), rand(), rand(), rand()],
        backgroundColor: `rgb(${rand()},${rand()},${rand()})`,
        type: 'line',
      },

<Bar data={chartData}/>
```

When I run this on react, this gives me the error like the below

```
  Type '{ labels: string[]; datasets: ({ label: string; data: number[]; backgroundColor: string; type?: undefined; } | { label: string; data: number[]; backgroundColor: string; type: string; })[]; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartData<"bar", number[], string>'.
    Types of property 'datasets' are incompatible.
      Type '({ label: string; data: number[]; backgroundColor: string; type?: undefined; } | { label: string; data: number[]; backgroundColor: string; type: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'ChartDataset<"bar", number[]>[]'.
        Type '{ label: string; data: number[]; backgroundColor: string; type?: undefined; } | { label: string; data: number[]; backgroundColor: string; type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartDataset<"bar", number[]>'.
          Type '{ label: string; data: number[]; backgroundColor: string; type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartDataset<"bar", number[]>'.
            Type '{ label: string; data: number[]; backgroundColor: string; type: string; }' is not assignable to type '_DeepPartialObject<{ type: "bar"; } & BarControllerDatasetOptions>'.
              Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
                Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"bar" | undefined'.
    276 |           </Box>
    277 |           <Box className={classes.historyChart}>
  > 278 |             <Bar data={chartData} options={chartOptions} />
        |                  ^^^^
    279 |           </Box>
    280 |         </>
    281 |       )}
```

Can anyone help me to make this work? I can't seem to find any solution on internet

Answer (score 2):

The type definitions are overly restrictive. You can work around this by casting to `any`.

```
type: 'line' as any,
```

Comment: Resulted in the whole chart not being drawn at all, here ( using react-chartjs-2 (with chartjs v3 backend))

Answer (score 1):

Try making these changes and see if it works for you:

1. `type: 'line' as const`
2. `<Chart type='bar' data={chartData} />` (ensure you import Chart from react-chartjs-2).

Comment: Results in console error`Uncaught Error: "point" is not a registered element.` and chart not being drawn here.

Comment: It seems you haven't registered the `PointElement`. Check out this link [How to fix "... is not a registered element" error?](https://react-chartjs-2.netlify.app/faq/registered-element) to the react-chartjs doc for more.

Answer (score 1):

You can union them in the type args like `'bar' | 'line'` ...

```
// . . .

import type { ChartOptions, LegendItem, ChartDataset } from 'chart.js';

import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import type { TypedChartComponent } from 'react-chartjs-2/dist/types';
   
type BarOrLine = 'bar' | 'line';

export type ChartCfg = {
  seriesData: null | {
    labels: (number | string)[];
    datasets: ChartDataset<BarOrLine>[];
  };
  options: ChartOptions<BarOrLine>;
};

const MixedChartComponent = Line as TypedChartComponent<BarOrLine>;

// . . .

const MixedChart: React.FC<{ chartCfg: ChartCfg }> = ({ chartCfg }) =>
  chartCfg.seriesData && <MixedChartComponent data={chartCfg.seriesData} options={chartCfg.options} />;

export default MixedChart;
```